# Java search a given element in a list

Tags: java, list, search

So, imagine I've got a

```
List<String> colours = {"blue", "red, "green", "yellow}
```

And another one :

```
List<String> desiredColours = {"black", "red", "yellow", "white" }
```

How can I do if I want to know which colour from the `desiredColours` is in `colours``

I could do it with a double `for`, but I would like to know if there is any already existing Java Function which already does it. Or at least someting like

```
for ( String colour : desiredColours ){
      if (colourisIn(colour, colours)){
           res.add(colour)
      }
}
```

Comment: `desiredColours.retainAll(colours)`.

Comment: Thanks ! I knew there will be something this easy in Java